# Accessing multidimensional array in JS created by PHP's json_encode

Tags: php, javascript, json

Here is some PHP code:

```
$map[1][3]['test'][0]='weee';
$map[4][5]['test'][0]='bleh';
$map[1][3]['bleh'][0]='mooo';
$map[1][3]['bleh'][1]='baaa';
echo "map = " . json_encode($map) . ";";
```

How do I access these items in Javascipt?

I've tried all sorts:

```
map[1][3]['bleh'][1]
map[1][3].bleh[1]
map.1.3.bleh[1]
```

but nothing seems to work :(

Thanks!

Comment: `map[1][3]['bleh'][1]` works fine for me. Scope issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me, except for your last one

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php

$map[1][3]['test'][0]='weee';
$map[4][5]['test'][0]='bleh';
$map[1][3]['bleh'][0]='mooo';
$map[1][3]['bleh'][1]='baaa';

print "map = ".json_encode($map).";\n";
?>

alert(map[1][3]['bleh'][1]);
alert(map[1][3].bleh[1]);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm yes, my example does work, I should have checked haha! Sorry... will investigate further

Comment: Turns out the issue was caused by lack of casting when creating the initial array using simplexml! What a headache haha